# Gauss-Jordan is ALWAYS consistent with Cramer`s rule .

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

When using Gauss - Jordan elimination to solve a system of linear equations, is the solution you get after obtaining a matrix in Reduced Row Echelon Form **THE** solution or is there any chance that not all are solutions.

For example *solve for x and y* in

> ```
>                                  2x + 5y = 4 
>
>                                   x + 3y = 7
> ```

in the matrix (1 0, 0 1) = (-13 10) in *RREF*

**x** = -13 while **y** = 10

Next I used Cramer`s Rule to verify the solution with a different method, and it turned out that the **x** I got from the Gauss-Jordan method was wrong.

Actual answer : x=-23 and y=10

Comment: You did your first computation incorrectly; it is easy to check that $x=-13,y=10$ is not actually a solution.

Comment: I thought that once you get a matrix in RREF the solutions you get are outright the actual solutions to the system.

Comment: You do. You must have made a mistake computing the RREF.

Comment: Oh yes. My mind was malfunctioning. Thanks for clearing things up.

Comment: You get my upvote for the cute title change.